# Alternative way to using for loop

Tags: python

Suppose a file looks like this:

```
abcd 1
abcd 2
abcd 3
xyz 1
xyz 2
```

My code:

```
if "abcd" in line:
  do something 

elif "xyz" in line:
  do something
```

If both "abcd" and "xyz" dynamically change, how would I capture them by writing the same loop?

Edit:

Can I write a universal loop which counts the number of elements in abcd and xyz? without taking abcd and xyz in its condition.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically change'? Please provide an example

Comment: "both "abcd" and "xyz" dynamically change" do you mean "abcd" and "xyz" can be arbitrary strings *but is fixed when you run*?

Comment: What exactly means "dynamically change"?

Comment: Define "dynamically changing" and that's not a loop.

Comment: YiFei has the right idea.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter is that the kind of thing you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I've understood correctly your question, but here's a possible way to gather key & values from your file:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

file = """


abcd      1
abcd       2
abcd        3
xyz        1
xyz       2




"""

output = defaultdict(list)

for line in file.split("\n"):
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue

    key, value = re.search(r'(.*?)\s+(.*)', line).groups()
    output[key].append(value)

print(output)

for k, v in output.iteritems():
    print("{0} has {1} items".format(k, len(v)))
```

Comment: How would make it count the number of elements contained by each key?Also, what if file is an external file and not something defined internally?

Comment: @identical123456 I've edited my question providing the count of the number of elements per key. Version is for python 2.x, if you're using 3.x replace iteritems() with items()

Comment: What if the format is in the form of abcd a1 , abcd a2, abcd b1 etc.. And I needed to count the number of a's of type abcd and number of b's of type abcd and similarly for any other strings

Answer (score 0):

You can always use variables for matching, using your example:

```
pattern1 = "abcd"
pattern2 = "xyz"
for line in lines_list:
    if pattern1 in line:
        do_smth
    elif pattern2 in line:
        do_smth2
    pattern1 = get_new_pattern1()
    pattern2 = get_new_pattern2()
```

Also you can split line to words with

```
first, second = line.split(' ')
```

use this in loop to get access to first and second word in line correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I catch your intention, but I hope the following code will help you. `keywords` simulates the **dynamically changing** variable.

```
keywords = ['abcd', 'xyz', '123']
data = ['abcd',
        'xyz',
        'asdf',
        'asdf',
        '456',
        'abcd',
        'xyz',
        'abcd',
        'xyz',
        'abcd',
        'xyz',
        'abcd',
        'xyz',
        '123',
        '123']


counts = [ data.count(kw) for kw in keywords]
print(counts)  # [5, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question (And making an assumption), it seems as though you want to go through each line in a file and than check if the text at that line matches something else. Say you have a file file.txt that is:

```
abcd 1
abcd 2
abcd 3
xyz 1
xyz 2
```

To read that file, you would do:

```
filedata = open('file.txt', 'r') # Where r means read
first_match = 'abcd'
second_match = 'xyz'
for line in text:
    if first_match in line:
        # Do stuff here
    elif second_line in line:
        # Do other stuff here
    first_match = change_first_match()
    second_match = change_second_match()
```

More information on reading files [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this (some kind of dynamic-keyword counter):

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    d=dict()
    for line in f:
        line=line.rstrip("\n")
        s=line.split(" ") # works iff you have only space as delimeter
        if s[0] in d:
            d[s[0]]+=int(s[1]) # replace by 1 if needed
        else:
            d[s[0]]=int(s[1]) # replace by 1
    #print(d)
```